# create array multidimensional php in more loop [edit]

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

i have this code php:

```
foreach($first as $row2){  // cycling once

       foreach($second as $row){   //    cycles x times

                ....
                echo $Hval1;//course changes value every cycle
                echo $Hval2;//course changes value every cycle

                $HeaderArray[]=array('Hval1'=>$Hval1,'Hval2'=>$Hval2); 

                    for($i=0;$i<$conta;++$i){   //    cycles x times

                       ....
                       echo $Bval1;//course changes value every cycle
                       echo $Bval2;//course changes value every cycle
                       echo $bval3;//course changes value every cycle

                    $BArray[]= array('Bval1'=>$Bval1,'Bval2'=>$Bval2,'Bval3'=>$Bval3);
                    $groupsArray[]=array($BArray);
                    }//end for cycles
                    $blockArray[]=array('header'=>$headerArray,'mach'=>$groupsArray);

       } //end second cycles
       $totalArray[]=('incontri'=>$blockArray);


} //end first cycle

echo print_r($totalArray);
```

for each $second cycle there are one o more groups $groupsArray Bval 'mach' (cycle for) going in the same array. All these (cycle $second) go into a Array 'incontri'.

I would like to get an array like this:

```
 ['incontri'
          [
           [
           'header'['Hval1'=>$Hval1,'Hval2'=>$Hval2],
           'mach'[
                  ['Bval1'=>$Bval1,'Bval2'=>$Bval2,'Bval3'=>$Bval3],
                  ['Bval1'=>$Bval1,'Bval2'=>$Bval2,'Bval3'=>$Bval3]
                  ]
           ],
           [
           'header'['Hval1'=>$Hval1,'Hval2'=>$Hval2],
           'mach'[
                 ['Bval1'=>$Bval1,'Bval2'=>$Bval2,'Bval3'=>$Bval3],
                 ['Bval1'=>$Bval1,'Bval2'=>$Bval2,'Bval3'=>$Bval3]
                 ]
           ],
           ...
          ]
]
```

my code php not work fine;

Comment: This question was re-asked @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42567211/creating-array-of-loop .  The question is better formed there by giovy and has an answer.  I move to close this question as an inferior duplicate.  (but I can't flag it until the other question is upvoted or the answer is accepted.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating array of loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42567211/creating-array-of-loop)